# CSS 'How to center navigation bar along with an image?'

Tags: html, css

Already browsed through other similar posts, couldn't find a similar one with a logo problem.

I am currently trying to center the navigation bar along with a logo. So everything fits perfectly and the logo is between `Products` & `Services`

I am just starting out on CSS, have very basic knowledge.

Also, could someone help me out with centering? - I need the nav bar to run across the page centered. As you see my is not centered.

Thanks

```css
img{
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css" type="text/css">


  </head>
  <body>


<img src="logo.png">

<div class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>


  <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</div>





  </body>

<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: are you trying to center horizontally or vertically? (or both?)

Comment: Hi,  horizontally sir

Comment: @Eduard I hate to be *"that"* guy but the amount of white space in your HTML is unnecessary.

Comment: @Eduard Also, only the `<head>`/`<body>` elements can go in the `<html>` element, your`<script>` tags should go at the bottom of the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image and nav items to be on the same line you can put the div in your `.nav` div. You can then center your `.nav` div using:

```
.nav {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To align the text items with the image you can also add `display: inline` to your `ul` element within your `.nav` div.

See example below:

```css
img {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav { /* center nav div */
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
      <li><img src="https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/hubfs/B2B-SO/images/logo-so-PRINT-4.png" /></li>
      <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: That is great Nick! One thing.. How would I center the img? Between `Products` and `Services`?

Comment: @Eduard you could add it as a list item within your `ul` tag. See my updated post, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Perfection! Is there an alternative way of inserting the img? The way my html is structured?

Comment: @Eduard yes, but I wouldn't say it is very straightforward. One way would be to use javascript, another could be to use the `:before` pseudo selector or another could perhaps involve using the `order` CSS property. The last two options would be quite finicky though to get working.

Comment: Ill have to carefully structure my HTML in future. Thanks for your help!.. learned a few valuable tips from this post :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to achieve something like this:

Note that the part below is for demonstration purpose only to highlight elements' position and size, which you can use while you are working with CSS.

```
.nav * {
   border: 1px solid;  
}
```

Also bare in mind, that you should set at least one of sizes, either `width` or `height`, of the image via attribute, instead of setting it within CSS. As soon as you set one size the other size is automatically calculated/scaled by the browser.

Further you can adjust the size of the image and the `margin-top` of the `img` element according to your needs.

```css
.nav {
   height: 50px;
}

.nav * {
   border: 1px solid;  
}

.nav img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img src="https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/hubfs/B2B-SO/images/logo-so-PRINT-4.png" height="25">
  
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>


    <li><a href="/">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to center elements is to apply `text-align: center` to their container div. In this case, add  `.nav{text-align: center;}` to your CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed.. did you want the logo centered too? If so, you can do this by adding `margin-left: 50%;` to the `.img` class. Alternatively, you could wrap the image in a div and use the text-align trick.